# Compilando código no Ubuntu e que execute no windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, compilação, gcc

Olá, eu queria saber como posso compilar um código em C no Ubuntu e que
execute no Windows. Eu tentei colocar a extensão ".exe" no final
do arquivo, mas quando  enviei o executável para meu professor ele disse
que não rodou.

Comment: Não sei avaliar ao certo, mas creio que essa pergunta esteja fora do escopo do site, de qualquer modo, dê uma olhada em [How to program for Windows in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14442/how-to-program-for-windows-in-ubuntu).

Comment: Mateus, obrigado por avisar =D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Você pode criar executáveis para o windows usando o [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). Digitando o seguinte comando, a gente pode ver a lista de pacotes disponíveis:

```
apt-cache search mingw-
```

> Dentre eles:

```
mingw-w64 - Development environment targeting 32- and 64-bit Windows
```

> Depois de instalá-lo:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

> Eu criei meu executável (32 bits) a partir da pasta `/usr/bin`, assim:

```
sudo i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
```

> Para 64 bits:

```
sudo x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld64.exe
```

> Resultado:

[image: resultado da compilação]

Fontes:
[How to install mingw32 on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389963/how-to-install-mingw32-on-ubuntu)
[How to compile for Windows on Linux with gcc/g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/how-to-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)
[Compile 64-bit binary with MinGW (Dev-C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988904/compile-64-bit-binary-with-mingw-dev-c)